# Lombok's lombok.copyableAnnotations not working with Jackson annotations

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I'm trying to make use of Lombok's new `copyableAnnotations` feature in order to have Jackson annotations like `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonValue` copied to generated getter/wither methods. This blog seems to suggest this should work: https://www.thecuriousdev.org/lombok-builder-with-jackson/. However, when I try this I simply get "error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration" (pointing to my `value` field). Why is this not working and how do I make it work? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how this feature is supposed to work. I'm using lombok 1.18.8.

**model.java:**

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;
import lombok.Value;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Value
public class BrandId implements ValueObject<Long> {

    @JsonCreator
    public static BrandId of(final Long value) {

        return new BrandId(value);
    }

    @NotNull
    @JsonValue
    private Long value;
}
```

**lombok.config:**

```
config.stopBubbling = true

lombok.copyableAnnotations += com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
lombok.copyableAnnotations += com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
lombok.copyableAnnotations += com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this not working […] ?

The `@JsonValue` annotation is only allowed on method declarations and on declarations of other annotation types; so, with or without Lombok, you can't put it on a field. (If you look at [its Javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html), you'll see that it's annotated with `@Target(value={ANNOTATION_TYPE,METHOD})`.)

The good news is that `@JsonValue` only applies to getter methods (not setter methods, builder methods, etc.), and there can be only one of it per class, so it's not a big deal to just manually create that one getter:

```java
    @NotNull
    private Long value;

    @JsonValue
    public Long getValue() {
        return value;
    }
```

If you really dislike that, then you can use Lombok's experimental `onMethod` feature:

```java
    @NotNull
    @Getter(onMethod=@__({@JsonValue}))
    private Long value;
```

which is equivalent to the above except in being experimental (so it may change or disappear in future versions of Lombok and/or Java).