# JsonIgnore annotation is not working with Lombok

Tags: maven, jackson, lombok

I am facing really weird issue with Lombok and Jackson. Following of piece of code on which I am working.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement
public class Order{

    //@JsonIgnore
    @Getter(onMethod = @__(@JsonIgnore))
    private boolean userPresent;
}
```

So what I want , this dto supposed to serialized as Json then this userPresent attribute should not come as response attribute. I though @JsonIgnore will work for me. But I think it as some issue with Lombok as per  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57119494/2111677 article.
Then I changed the approach to use OnMethod.

Now , on eclipse compiling perfectly fine but when I am trying to compile using mvn then it gives me following error.

[image]

Could someone help me fix when its not working with maven.

Comment: Which `Java` version do you use? Could you show an error message from `Maven`. Can you compile with `-X` param?

Answer (score 7):

The `@__` style is for javac7. For javac8+ you have to use this variant:

```
@Getter(onMethod_=@JsonIgnore)
```

However, it is sufficient to have the `@JsonIgnore` annotation on either the field, the getter, or the setter. If it is present on at least one of those, the whole "virtual property" is ignored completely during (de-)serialization. So if that is what you want, you don't need that `onMethod_`.

If you want it to be ignored only during serialization, but not on deserialization, you have to add a `@JsonProperty` on the setter:

```
@JsonIgnore
@Setter(onMethod_=@JsonProperty)
private boolean userPresent;
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not work, a workaround is using @JsonIgnoreProperties at class level:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"email"})
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class ProductColor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NonNull
    @Getter
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    @Getter
    private String color;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="colors")
    @Getter(onMethod_ = @JsonIgnore)
    private Set<Product> products;

}
```