# How to exclude boolean type value for jackson payload

Tags: java, jackson

I have really simple requirement to exclude Boolean type attribute from payload during Jackson serialization. Following is the piece of code that I want to fix that. I want exclude it always irrespective to its value.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement
public class Order{

    @JsonIgnore
    private boolean userPresent;
}
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: The above should should work for always right ? whats wrong with it ?

Comment: hi @Deadpool, I think it as has some issue with Lombok as per  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57119494/2111677 and as per doc. I also tried suggest version as well.
@Getter(onMethod = @__(@JsonIgnore))
    private boolean isBranchPresent; 
but this is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly add the `Getter` for the property you want to ignore and set the `@JsonIgnore` there:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement
public class Order{

  private boolean userPresent;

  @JsonIgnore
  public boolean isUserPresent() {
    return this.userPresent;
  }
}
```

If you don't have any other properties in the class, you should remove the `@Getter` annotation because it is redundant now.